# Taxonomy's title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've installed Woocomerce plugin and custom post type 'product'. There are also categories of this type named 'product_cat'. I need to display name of categories on single-product.php

I've tried in this way:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'name', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo $term->name; ?>
```

But it's unsucessful. When I checked the type that returned to *$term*, it displayed as boolean.

Comment: You want to display ALL product categories or just the product categories that this product is assigned to?

Comment: just the product categories that this product is assigned to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code will return all categories assigned to current product.

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $cat_name .= $term->name.', ';
    break;
}
echo $cat_name;
```

> add this code inside `single-product.php`

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: It's working too, but it's return all sub-categories too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [edit your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/247772/edit) to provide some context. *Why* do you think this answers the question? Consult [How do I write a good answer?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.